# Accidentally ran ifdown eth0 on AWS server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can't ssh into the server anymore. How do I run turn the network interface back on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reboot** the machine from AWS dashboard or using AWS CLI.

When the machine is rebooted, the network interface is brought up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the console through ILO and make the interface UP.